# A fictional world where morals and ethics are completely reversed?

Tags: society, culture, alternate-earth, ethics

I want to create a world that exist in an alternate universe where all ethics and moral behaviors on earth are completely reversed/backwards.

What would society in this alternate world look like?, to be more specific I would like to know:

1. How would people in this world interact with each other on a daily basis?
2. What would relationships look like?
3. What would your typical family look like?
4. What would religion look like?
5. What type of laws would the government construct to favor these backward morals?

Comment: It’s hard to say what it would mean to “reverse” everyone’s morals, especially when so many individuals already hold values that often contradict each other (e.g. honesty and politeness).

Comment: This is far too underspecified to answer coherently. Take, for example, the issue of Confucian filial piety. What exactly does it mean to "reverse" that? Should parents honor their children instead of children honoring their parents? Or should children hate and degrade their parents instead of honoring them? Or both--maybe parents should hate and degrade their children. In any case, however, I expect the ultimate answer to be some variation of "society collapses, and humanity goes extinct".

Comment: Religion would look like a large pink meringue. Relationships would look like Riemannian manifolds. Your typical family would look like a puffy dragon. In order to favor these backward morals the government would construct laws of polymorphic type. Seriously speaking, have you even *tried* to understand *any* of the philosophical theories on the basis of ethics and morality? Or do you believe that thousands of years of philosophical investigation are worthless? Can you articulate the meaning of the phrase *"morals and ethics are completely reversed"*?

Comment: My immediate thought was "Gelsomino in the Country of Liars" by Gianni Rodari. But after a quick Google search I discovered that this book was never officially translated to English. How come?!

Comment: It's kinda been done see https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_universe

Comment: @Alexander -  maybe you are the one predestined to do it!

Comment: Pierre - You are asking us to design your world for you. A full answer to your question would require a long essay, maybe even a book. We don't do that here. Instead, you could think this through yourself and then test your reasoning here in stages under a *reality-check* tag.

Comment: Definitely too many questions, but I think the underlying premise is quite interesting! I hope you'll consider editing this to make it conform to SE norms, and perhaps split it into different more focused queries!